# How can we create a Angular 5/6/7 Anti-clock Countdown (Milliseconds)?

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

How can we create a AntiClock wise Countdown using Angular 5/6/7 .

For.ex. (*countdown in milliseconds*)  **60.000** (60 seconds) .... moving anticlockwise 
for.ex.   ( **42.526** *in milliseconds* ) .

below codes give the output by refreshing interval by 1 seconds, our code needs interval in milliseconds, like above example .

Thanks

```
private _trialEndsAt;
private _diff: number;
private _days: number;
private _hours: number;
private _minutes: number;
private _seconds: number;
private _milliseconds: number;

ngOnInit() {
    this._trialEndsAt = "2018-12-28";
    Observable.interval(10).map((x) => {
        this._diff = Date.parse(this._trialEndsAt) - Date.parse(new Date().toString());
    }).subscribe((x) => {
        this._days = this.getDays(this._diff);
        this._hours = this.getHours(this._diff);
        this._minutes = this.getMinutes(this._diff);
        this._seconds = this.getSeconds(this._diff);
        this._milliseconds = this.getMilliseconds(60000);
    });
}

getDays(t){
    return Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
}

getHours(t){
    return Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
}

getMinutes(t){
    return Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
}

getSeconds(t){
    return Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
}

getMiliseconds(t){
    return Math.floor( (t) % 1000 );
}
```

Comment: What problem exactly do you have with the code you posted?

Comment: actually this countdown works, reducing from 60 -> 0 from one second interval. our requirement is to make it from 60.000 -> 41.856 -> 0.000 in milliseconds ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the interval to something smaller than 1000.

```
Observable.interval(x).map(
```

you need to repace **x** with value between 0 and 1000. this value is refreshing interval.

and put function for milliseconds

```
getMiliseconds(t){
   return Math.floor( (t) % 1000 );
}
```

Please check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-78vx6q

Comment: which value, that we need to change, i created a new variable called _milliseconds and similarly applied as others, it shows only, 0 no movements.

Comment: try `Observable.interval(10)`

Comment: please look at the edited questions, i have made the changes as per your answer. but result still shows 0

Comment: `this._milliseconds = this.getMilliseconds(this._diff);`

Comment: still '0' print no movements.

Comment: please check my solution on stackblitz

Comment: Is that possible to stop the countdown timer, when it shows negative value.  { _seconds   =  -59 } .